# How to compile wasm in a worker thread in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, web-worker, worker

I have a bundle like this that is not electron-ready apparently:

```js
const path = require('path').join(__dirname, 'my_project_bg.wasm');
const bytes = require('fs').readFileSync(path);
let imports = {};
imports['./my_project'] = require('./my_project');

const wasmModule = new WebAssembly.Module(bytes);
const wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule, imports);
module.exports = wasmInstance.exports;
```

Trying to run it in Electron I get this error:

> WebAssembly.Compile is disallowed on the main thread, if the buffer size is larger than 4KB. Use WebAssembly.compile, or compile on a worker thread.

My question is, (apart from producing and using an async bundle), what are the steps to compile it in a worker thread and avoid any hassle? examples appreciated.

Comment: Hi rocco , just checking if you was able to solve this